# AS3 Running an External Program

Tags: actionscript-3, external

So I am making something for a bit of fun but I was just wondering if it was possible to run an external program for example opening Chrome (and maybe even searching on it) by pressing a button.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in chrome? Does it have to be chrome specifically or do you just want to open a website in browser?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to launch an external program by wrapping your .swf file. There are multiples ways to do that:

1. You can use the Flash to [create a projector](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/exporting-projector-files.html) which will allow to use [fscommand()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html#fscommand()) with the exec argument: `fscommand("exec","/path/to/your/installed/Chrome");`
2. You can create an AIR application and use [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html)
3. Use a 3rd party wrapper (such as [mProjector](http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector), [zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/), etc.)

First option should be easiest to test. Keep in mind that this feature has been coming and going with various versions of Flash. In older versions of Flash you simple used the Standalone Flash Player and Create Projector option from the File Menu. As long as you can use this feature, this is the simplest, but you won't have a lot of options.

If you plan to have more control over the application you're launching from as3, consider using AIR as you get access to the filesystem and processes.

The 3rd party tools may be outdated now and for a simple app launch may be overkill, but it's good to know they're there (in case you may need some otherwise unsupported feature)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, flash can't call external programs without AIR.
But if this case allows to use ActiveX, it's possible to run some external programs.
Needless to say, it works on IE only.

JS Code

```
    function openChrome(url){
        wshshell=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        wshshell.run("chrome.exe --new-window " + url);
    }
    function openExcel(path){
        wshshell=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        wshshell.run("excel " + path);
    }
```

AS Code

```
ExternalInterface.call("openChrome", "http://www.google.com");
ExternalInterface.call("openExcel", "C:\\foo\\bar.xlsx");
```